# show div while load is executing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to show a div that That indicates that the page is loading, for the load I use the jquery load event, however, the load div always stays on the page and there is no hidden end load, my code is this:

```
$("#mydiv").fadeIn("fast");
                $('#page').load('myphp.php', { 'data': id },function(){
                     $("#mydiv").fadeOut("fast");
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `$('#page').ajaxStart(callback);` and `$('#page').ajaxStop(callback);`.
look here:

https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/

Answer (score 1):

Hide the `div` when the document finishes loading via

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mydiv").fadeOut("fast");
    });
```

(include this code after the rest of your JS in the header), e.g.

1. HTML headers
2. JS/jQuery
3. this^
4. CSS link
5. HTML body contents